# Does the Air Walk spell require a Fly action?

Tags: spells, flight, pathfinder-2e

The end of the [Fly action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=94) states:

> If you’re airborne at the end of your turn and didn’t use a Fly action this round, you fall.

However, it also requires you to have a fly speed. While this makes perfect sense for the [*Fly*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=125) spell, the [*Air Walk*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=6) spell says:

> The target can walk on air as if it were solid ground.

This gives the target the ability to move through the air, but it doesn't specifically say it's a move speed. Additionally, if the target treats the air as solid ground, they wouldn't normally need to spend an action to not fall through the "floor."

My concern is that these two spells are the same level, but seem to function very differently. Does the *Air Walk* spell necessitate the usage of the Fly action, or does it literally allow you to stand on air?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It does not

[Air Walk](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=6) allows you to treat air as if it were the ground. So you can move both vertically (with a 45 degree angle) and horizontally (as normal). But you are at no risk of falling as you are already touching "the ground". It doesn't allow you to fly, nor grants you a fly speed. As such, it shouldn't be treated as if your character is flying.